# How does Firestore save dates?

Tags: firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I've recently discovered `firestore.Timestamp` and so I tried to assign `firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();` to one and it didn't work. instead it says `Type 'FieldValue' is not assignable to type 'Timestamp'` which I would say is strange. Shouldn't `serverTimestamp()` be a `Timestamp` and not a `FieldValue`? What would be the purpose of `firestore.Timestamp` if not to save timestamps to Firestore? Is there a way to get a server timestamp that is compatible with `firestore.Timestamp` or should I be avoiding timestamps altogether, and just stick to `firestore.FieldValue` for all my dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serverTimestamp()` just returns sentinel value that tells the Firestore server that it should use the current time **on the server** as the value for the field you're trying to set.  It doesn't return an actual Timestamp object itself.

The reason why you'd use this is to make sure that dates are being set consistently on the server instead of depending on the clock being correct on the user's device.

If you want to know the current time on the device, just use the native date/time objects provided by the language or operating system.

Comment: I was using `timestamp = firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();` and it would say I can't do that because `Type 'FieldValue' is not assignable to type 'Timestamp'` so I tried `timestamp = <any>firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();` and the error went away. Any reason I shouldn't do this?

Comment: As I said in my answer, serverTimestamp() doesn't return a timestamp.  You use it in place of an actual Timestamp to set the date on field in a document.

Comment: Right, I am just doing this, then saving it to Firestore as part of a larger object. In my situation `timestamp` is of type `firestore.Timestamp`. I could elaborate and say it's `myObject.timestamp = <any>firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();` then I update my Firestore doc `myDocRef.update(myObject)` so I need to assign `firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` to a `firestore.Timestamp`

Comment: Yeah, as I said, it doesn't return a Timestamp.  The error message is telling you what it's returning - a FieldValue.  Type your variable correctly, then use it in your update.  Just use the FieldValue where you would normally pass a Timestamp.

Comment: Ok I get it. I'm using a `firestore.Timestamp` when I should be using a `FieldValue`. Are timestamps in Firestore not saved as `firestore.Timestamp` ? What would the purpose of a `firestore.Timestamp` be if not to save the timestamp to Firestore? I realize `firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` returns a `firestore.FieldValue` on the server-side, but why is there a `firestore.Timestamp` at all then, if we can't use it with `serverTimestamp()`?

Comment: Firestore converts the serverTimestamp sentinel value to an actual Timestamp to store in the document.

Comment: So if I understand this right, this would be why Firestore was telling me to do `timestampsInSnapshots: true` and `timestamp.toDate();` because in the past dates were stored as `firestore.FieldValue` but they changed it to `firestore.Timestamp`, I'm just guessing, but that would explain all my problems... is that what they did on that last update?

Comment: No, the server timestamp sentinel value has always been there.  The only thing that changed was was the representation of date objects as Timestamp instead of platform native dates.  Native dates have millisecond precision, while Timestamp has nanosecond precision.

Comment: ohh, ok I get it. Thanks for all your help!